# Apache POI error opening workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

This is the code and classes imported

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;


public boolean openWorkbook(java.io.File file){

        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileInputStream);
```

And when I do create in the workbook factory, I get the error below but only if the file is a XLXS file. Old file format XLS files work fine.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key   access_properties_not_allowed
```

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi, I tried that code in my place (using version 3.11 ) and the error doesn't happen. So, could you put the complete stack trace so that we can check  the poi source? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here

https://guedebyte.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/the-odyssey-of-loading-a-class-in-a-eclipse-plugin-or-how-we-integrated-docx4j-in-poi4xpages

I need to change the classpath in the current thread so Apache POI can find all resources.

Comment: Please accept your answer, if it is appropriate so that it will no more remain an unanswered question.